# DSGE Bayesian estimation - Sum of Squares equivalence

Tags: dsge, structural-estimation

Say I have a DSGE that produces several observable outputs (e.g. GDP, inflation, interest rate), and I want to estimate this model using empirical data (in the form of a set of time series of the observables).

I understand there are several options:

1. Bayesian estimation
2. Maximum Likelihood (MLE)
3. Minimising least-squares (i.e. weighted least squares, WLS)

The 3rd option requires choosing weights for each time series, and the choice of weights is non-obvious. My question is:

**If I do Bayesian or MLE estimation, can I figure out the equivalent WLS weights that would have given me the same answer?**

(A weak analogy to this question for a different context would be: "If I use frequentist method X, what Bayesian prior would [give me the same answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/247760/what-is-are-the-implicit-priors-in-frequentist-statistics)?". Though as I say, weak analogy.)

My understanding is that in some univariate cases, MLE is equivalent to univariate OLS without weights, but this is not the situation here.

Comment: Difficult to answer precisely, because you give few information on the MLE and NLS estimators you consider. In the multivariate case MLE and NLS are asymptotically equivalent in many but not all cases, it depends on the underlying assumptions (on the distribution of the unobserved random term for instance). Advanced textbooks discuss the equivalence precisely.